# How can I remove a large, half-page gap in a list paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm busy formatting a document but there's a random gap as much as half a page of blank space in between two points in a list paragraph:

[image: large gap on page]

There is nothing hidden, like a table, and it also doesn't allow me to select the empty space - the cursor selects the last word in the previous paragraph and the first word of the next with nothing in between. I've checked the show/hide icon, there is nothing there. I've adjusted the line spacing, paragraph alignment, page layout, nothing changes (some even made it worse).

How can I remove this large gap?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a page break before the first paragraph on the second page. To remove this page break, right-click in the first paragraph on the second page and select "Paragraph..." to open the Paragraph dialog. Here, uncheck the 'page break before' option.

The 'keep with next' checkbox in the Paragraph dialog box can also cause similar behavior, so uncheck this if needed.

Comment: Nice [addition](https://superuser.com/revisions/1701488/2)

Comment: @saaru-lindestøkke Apologies, I was still playing with Word myself and did not see your post. I have removed the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is caused the use of line breaks in list item 2c together with the paragraph option [*Keep lines together*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d).

To fix this, right-click on point c (on the right page in the screenshot) and click *Paragraph*:

[image]

Then go to the *Line and Page Breaks* tab and uncheck the option *Keep lines together*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Saaru, it was a 'keep line together' issue :-)